# How to for each row in a DataFrame, aggregate data from N other DataFrames (on a specific column) where the ID matches

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to aggregate data from several Pandas DataFrames to perform analysis on it.

I have a master DataFrame that contains player information e.g.:

```
Master
   Id    FullName TwitterHandle
0  1   John Smith  a
1  2   Ray Duke    b
2  3   Max Welby   c
```

Additionally I have 14 DataFrames that contain different stat sources. The number of sources fluctuates per run so it would ideally not be hardcoded 
e.g. this would not be ideal.

```
Master["Mean_Hits"] = (source1["Hits"] + source2["Hits"] + ... + sourceN["Hits"]) / N
```

They data sources all have the same players, but different predictions. The Id in this table corresponds to the Id from the master DataFrame. The master data frame contains considerably more players than the data sources, and ideally the non-matches would just be zeroed out instead of removed.

e.g. Data Sources

```
source1
   Id  Hits  RBIs
0  1   50    10
1  2   100   25
2  3   22    3

source2
   Id  Hits  RBIs
0  1   40    12
1  2   75    20
2  3   33    6
```

I want to from each source aggregate each column into a mean and add that column to the master dataframe. So from N DataFrames it would aggregate Hits and divide by N and update the master DataFrame so it was now:

Desired Output:

```
   Id    FullName OtherPersonalInfo            Mean_Hits            Mean_RBIs
0  1   John Smith  a                               45.00                11.00
1  2   Ray Duke    b                               87.50                22.50
2  3   Max Welby   c                               27.50                 4.50
```

I would do this for each "stat" column and on all of them take the original column name and prefix it with "Mean_".

I can obviously do this very slowly by iterating over the rows in the master DataFrame and selecting the matching rows in each source to extract the values.

I know that this can't be an uncommon use case in pandas, so there must be a better way.

Code to create basic example of data sources:

```
    import pandas as pd
    master_table_dict = {
        "Id": [1, 2, 3],
        "FullName": ["John Smith", "Ray Duke", "Max Welby"],
        "OtherPersonalInfo": ["a", "b", "c"],
    }
    data_source_one_dict = {"Id": [1, 2, 3], "Hits": [50, 100, 22], "RBIs": [10, 25, 3]}
    data_source_two_dict = {"Id": [1, 2, 3], "Hits": [40, 75, 33], "RBIs": [12, 20, 6]}
    master = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(master_table_dict)
    sources = {
        "source1": pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_source_one_dict),
        "source2": pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data_source_two_dict),
    }
```

Comment: this is not a [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) , you could post a master df ad 2 dfs from stat sources and post an expected output(and mention that it is just not 2 but many dfs)

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation. I updated with minimum example of master and two data sources and provided Python code to generate the minimum example DataFrames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can can `concat` and groupby on `Id` the `merge` on `Id`:

```
d=pd.concat(sources.values(),ignore_index=True).groupby('Id',as_index=False).mean()
master.merge(d,on='Id')
```

---

```
   Id    FullName OtherPersonalInfo  Hits  RBIs
0   1  John Smith                 a  45.0  11.0
1   2    Ray Duke                 b  87.5  22.5
2   3   Max Welby                 c  27.5   4.5
```

Comment: I don't know why I was struggling so hard to come up with this. This is exactly what I needed to do. I just added a rename on the aggregated DataFrame columns to append "Mean_" and now I have a stew going.

Comment: @Stooby hey. its fine. this happens to all of us.. :) no worries